# Jquery head tags issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, head

I have gone crazy for hours testing some jquery scripts in my site and nothing was working, while it would work on Fiddles...

So here is what I have in my :

Then I have a script as below but I can't get it to work!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(":checkbox").bind("click", function(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".itemBox:not(#" + $(this).val() + ")").hide();
        $(".itemBox[id='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
    } else {
        $(".itemBox").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure that jQuery is properly loaded on your site?

Comment: Not sure at all it's being properly loaded, actually part of the post got deleted. I have this in the head tags:
' <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have wait for the document to load before you can bind events to it.

jQuery provides an easy way to do that, by [calling the `ready` method on the document](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), and putting all your code inside that function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // All of your code should go in this function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the code a bit, used document ready to make sure that the element is there before you attach the event handler.

```
jQuery( function() {  //wait for document to be ready
    //$(":checkbox").on("click", function (event)  //should really use on() if it is jQuery 1.7+
    $(":checkbox").bind("click", function (event) {  //bind is deprecated
        var cb = jQuery(this),
            items = $(".itemBox");
        if (cb.is(':checked')) {
            items.hide();
            $("#" + cb.val()).show();
        } else {
            items.show();
        }
        cb = items = null;
    });
});
```